Unable to use Artifactory HTTPS
I am now forced to use HTTPS on the page, but I am unable to access it through HTTPS
I don't want to access through reverse proxy
After consulting the official documentation and adding configurations according to the official documentation, it still doesn't work
https://jfrog.com/help/r/artifactory-how-to-enable-tls-within-the-jfrog-platform/artifactory-how-to-enable-tls-within-the-jfrog-platform
This is my startup command
docker run -d \
           --name artifactory \
           --restart=always \
           -p 1446:8081 \
           -p 1447:8082 \
           -p 1448:8443 \
           -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime \
           -v /etc/localtime:/etc/timezone \
           -v /artifactory/var/:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory \
           -v /artifactory/certs:/certs \
           releases-docker.jfrog.io/jfrog/artifactory-pro:7.84.16

system.yaml
shared:
    ## Java 17 distribution to use
    #javaHome: "JFROG_HOME/artifactory/app/third-party/java"

    ## Extra Java options to pass to the JVM. These values add to or override the defaults.
    #extraJavaOpts: "-Xms512m -Xmx2g"

    ## Security Configuration
    security:
    ## Join key value for joining the cluster (takes precedence over 'joinKeyFile')
    #joinKey: "<Your joinKey>"

    ## Join key file location
    #joinKeyFile: "<For example: JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/etc/security/join.key>"

    ## Master key file location
    ## Generated by the product on first startup if not provided
    #masterKeyFile: "<For example: JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/etc/security/master.key>"

    ## Maximum time to wait for key files (master.key and join.key)
    #bootstrapKeysReadTimeoutSecs: 120

    ## Node Settings
    node:
    ## A unique id to identify this node.
    ## Default auto generated at startup.
    #id: "art1"

    ## Default auto resolved by startup script
    #ip:

    ## Sets this node as primary in HA installation
    #primary: true

    ## Sets this node as part of HA installation
    #haEnabled: true

    ## Database Configuration
    database:
        ## To run Artifactory with any database other than PostgreSQL allowNonPostgresql set to true.
        #allowNonPostgresql: false
        allowNonPostgresql: true

        ## One of mysql, oracle, mssql, postgresql, mariadb
        ## Default Embedded derby

        ## Example for postgresql
        #type: postgresql
        #driver: org.postgresql.Driver
        #url: "jdbc:postgresql://<your db url, for example: localhost:5432>/artifactory"
        #username: artifactory
        #password: password


## ARTIFACTORY TEMPLATE
artifactory:
  ## Artifactory Tomcat connector customization on the Artifactory port
  tomcat:
    ## Set up an HTTPS connector for artifactory. This opens a port 
    ## in addition to the default HTTP connector. All relevant 
    ## properties configured for the HTTP connector are applied also
    ## for this connector (e.g. "maxThreads")
    httpsConnector:
      ## Enable connector with SSL/TLS
      #enabled: false
      enabled: true

      ## Port to use for the HTTPS connector
      #port: 8443
      port: 8443

      ## Certificate file to use
      #certificateFile: "$JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/etc/artifactory/security/ssl/server.crt"
      certificateFile: "/certs/server.crt"

      ## Certificate key file to use.
      #certificateKeyFile: "$JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/etc/artifactory/security/ssl/server.key"
      certificateKeyFile: "/certs/server.key"

      ## Extra configuration for the HTTPS connector.
      ## For example extraConfig: "SSLProtocol='TLSv1+TLSv1.1+TLSv1.2'"
      #extraConfig: ""
access:
  security:
    tls: true

Why am I still unable to access it https://server:1448
I can't use reverse proxy
Reviewed official documentation and redeployed

Does the browser trust the certificates? Are you able to reach Artifactory via http unsafe or the application simply doesn't come up?

I use http://server:1447 , can access the service normally
